# I want to get specific string from a text file

Tags: javascript, string, testing, find

> Following is the log from which i just wanted to get the string at its end which is "Total conversion time (11766 element(s))|36565 millisecs" and it's number will be change in the new run . like may be second time if i run the software i get "Total conversion time (12366 element(s))|36465 millisecs"

++ LOG> INFO  DgnV8Converter.Performance - Convert Spatial Elements> Model 'Office Building' (2 element(s))|64 millisecs
[ ] Converting Elements: Model: Architecture                                                                                    :6/3        +++ LOG> INFO  DgnV8Converter.Performance - Convert Spatial Elements> Model 'Architecture' (8257 element(s))|5640 millisecs
[ ] Converting Elements: Model: Civil                                                                                           :6/2        +++ LOG> INFO  DgnV8Converter.Performance - Convert Spatial Elements> Model 'Civil' (164 element(s))|183 millisecs
[ ] Converting Elements: Model: MEP                                                                                             :6/1        +++ LOG> INFO  DgnV8Converter.Performance - Convert Spatial Elements> Model 'MEP' (2916 element(s))|3593 millisecs
[ ] Converting Elements: Model: Structural                                                                                      :6/0        +++ LOG> INFO  DgnV8Converter.Performance - Convert Spatial Elements> Model 'Structural' (427 element(s))|493 millisecs
+++ LOG> INFO  DgnV8Converter.Performance - Convert Spatial Elements (total)|10047 millisecs
[ ] Converting Drawings:                                                                                                        :5/0        +++ LOG> INFO  DgnV8Converter.Performance - Convert Drawings (total)|3 millisecs
[ ] Converting Sheets:                                                                                                          :4/0        +++ LOG> INFO  DgnV8Converter.Performance - Convert Sheets (total)|3 millisecs
[ ] Converting Sheets: Model: Office Building                                                                                   :4/4        +++ LOG> INFO  DgnV8Converter.Performance - Convert NamedGroups in dictionary (0 element(s))|4 millisecs
[ ] Converting Sheets: Converting Relationships                                                                                 :4/0        +++ LOG> INFO  DgnV8Converter.Performance - Convert Elements> ECRelationships: Dropped indices for bulk insertion into BisCore:ElementRefersToElements class hierarchy.|1 millisecs
+++ LOG> INFO  DgnV8Converter.Performance - Convert Elements> NamedGroups|247 millisecs
+++ LOG> INFO  DgnV8Converter.Performance - Convert Elements> ECRelationships (total)|2 millisecs
+++ LOG> INFO  DgnV8Converter.Performance - Convert Elements> ECRelationships: Recreated indices for BisCore:ElementRefersToElements class hierarchy.|11 millisecs
[ ] Embedding Files:                                                                                                            :3/0        [ ] Embedding Fonts:                                                                                                            :2/0        [ ] Creating Thumbnails:                                                                                                        :1/0        [ ] Creating Thumbnails: View: Model - View 1                                                                                   :1/8        [ ] Creating Thumbnails: View: Kitchen                                                                                          :1/7        [ ] Creating Thumbnails: View: First Floor Office Space                                                                         :1/6        [ ] Creating Thumbnails: View: Second Floor Open Space                                                                          :1/5        [ ] Creating Thumbnails: View: Third Floor Unfinished Space                                                                     :1/4        [ ] Creating Thumbnails: View: Aerial North Face                                                                                :1/3        [ ] Creating Thumbnails: View: Aerial West Face                                                                                 :1/2        [ ] Creating Thumbnails: View: Aerial South Face                                                                                :1/1        [ ] Creating Thumbnails: View: Front Entrance                                                                                   :1/0        +++ LOG> INFO  DgnV8Converter.Performance - Finish conversion|26396 millisecs
+++ LOG> INFO  DgnV8Converter.Performance - Total conversion time (11766 element(s))|36565 millisecs

```html
function ReadFileLines()
{
 var str,AFileName="D:\\ConverterElements\\bingo.log";
  var F, s;
  var s = aqFile.ReadWholeTextFile(AFileName, aqFile.ctANSI);
  Log.Message("File entire contents:");
  Log.Message(s);
    let aSubString="11766 element" 
    let Res = aqString.Find(s, aSubString)
    if ( Res != -1) 
    Log.Checkpoint("Element Count is same");
  else
    Log.Error("Element Count is Different");    
 }
```

strong text

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure whether this is what you are asking for. If you just want to extract "Total conversion time .....", from the string, you can use this

If `str` contains the log

```
str.substring(s.indexOf("Total conversion time"))
```